# Import csv file containing blanks

Tags: teradata

I am trying to import an CSV file which contains blanks for some fields to teradata SQL assistant. When the values get imported teradata treats the blank as a value and in case of integers it is imported as '0'. How can i import the blank values as null in teradata? Thank u in advance.

Comment: How is the column defined?  Is it nullable? Does it have a default value?

Comment: FastLoad, MultiLoad, BTEQ, SQL Assistant? What tool are you using? Can you share the code?

Comment: its in SQL Assistant. Am importing a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the blank values with ? in your raw file which you are importing to teradata.

Teradata will recconise and will display these as NULL

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer for a few days. Replacing all blank values with a question mark in the CSV file helped to load the data finally.